# How to check for not null fields before inserting record into a database table Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to create / insert a new record in a database table (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL) only by inserting the primary key field values. But this is not working if there is a column in the table which does not allow null values. How can I check the table columns which do not allow null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute a request against your table, for example at startup time, and then check the metadata of your table:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int nullable = rsmd.isNullable(1);
if(nullable == ResultSetMetadata.columnNullable) {
    System.out.println("Nullable");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just did the exact thing.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [DatabaseMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) object and in particular the [getAttributes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getAttributes%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

> NULLABLE int => whether NULL is allowed
>
> ```
> attributeNoNulls - might not allow NULL values
> attributeNullable - definitely allows NULL values
> attributeNullableUnknown - nullability unknown
> ```

I do think (however) that your application should know as much as possible re. the data constraints. The database protects itself with these constraints, but the application should (where possible) know and respect this info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this should work:
[ResultSetMetaData.isNullable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#isNullable%28int%29)

```
public int isNullable(int column)
           throws SQLException

Indicates the nullability of values in the designated column.

Parameters:
    column - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ... 
Returns:
    the nullability status of the given column; one of columnNoNulls, columnNullableor columnNullableUnknown 
Throws:
    SQLException - if a database access error occurs
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I get you right, you are looking for a way to test the tables in your program (and I assume not manually)...*
Test each table like this:
Step 1: Try inserting a record with null values to your table.
Step 2: If exception rises, catch it and proceed these steps with other tables.

You can mark those tables or have a list which contains tables' names for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could check ResultSetMetaData as well. [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

```
ResultSetMetaData.columnNullable
ResultSetMetaData.columnNoNulls
ResultSetMetaData.columnNullableUnknown
```

Regards